# Measuring width & height of images returns 0 in Chrome and Firefox, but works in Safari

Tags: jquery, css, image, onload, dimensions

I'm trying to give my images a landscape or portrait class in a Wordpress image gallery by measuring the images' dimensions on load. The code works in Safari, but Firefox returns a 0 pixel width and height, and Chrome sometimes loads them properly, and sometimes not. I'm pretty confused, could someone help me out?

```
jQuery(window).on('load', function () {

    jQuery(".blocks-gallery-grid img").each(function() {

        var aspectRatio = jQuery(this).css('width', 'auto').width()/jQuery(this).css('height', 'auto').height();
            console.log(jQuery(this).attr('src'));
            console.log(jQuery(this).width());
            console.log(jQuery(this).height());
        jQuery(this).data("aspect-ratio", aspectRatio);

        if(aspectRatio > 1) {
            jQuery(this).parent().parent().parent('li').addClass( "landscape" );

        } else if (aspectRatio < 1) {
            jQuery(this).parent().parent().parent('li').addClass( "portrait" );
        } else {
            jQuery(this).parent().parent().parent('li').addClass( "landscape" );           
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Not the source of the problem, but you really should use some variables here. You're creating 9 jQuery objects (`jQuery(this)`) on for each image. Why does the `else` branch the same as the `if` branch? Replace the `>` with `>=` and you can get rid of the `else` branch. You could also store `jQuery(this).parent().parent().parent('li')` in a variable so you don't have to change it on multiple place should the DOM structure change.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I'm not much of a programmer but I got this far through googling and reading up on websites. I'll try to improve my scripts with your advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(window).on('load', function() { 
    $(".blocks-gallery-grid img").each(function() {
        let _this = $(this),
            aspectRatio = _this.width()/_this.height(),
            parentLi = _this.closest('li');
            
        if(aspectRatio > 1) {
            parentLi.addClass( "landscape" );
        } else if (aspectRatio < 1) {
            parentLi.addClass( "portrait" );
        } else {
            parentLi.addClass( "landscape" );           
        }
    });
});
```

```css
img{
  max-width: 100%;
}
li{
   padding: 15px; 
   box-sizing: border-box; 
   border: 3px solid;
}
.landscape{
   border-color: red;
}
.portrait{
   border-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="blocks-gallery-grid">
  <li>
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff">
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x600/000/fff">
   </li>
</ul>
```

Could you try something like this:

```
$(window).on('load', function () {

    $(".blocks-gallery-grid img").each(function() {
        let _this = $(this);

        let aspectRatio = _this.width()/_this.height();

        _this.data("aspect-ratio", aspectRatio);

        if(aspectRatio > 1) {
            _this.parent().parent().parent('li').addClass( "landscape" );

        } else if (aspectRatio < 1) {
            _this.parent().parent().parent('li').addClass( "portrait" );
        } else {
            _this.parent().parent().parent('li').addClass( "landscape" );           
        }
    });
});
```

Also, I assume `li` is the only list item parent for that element, so you could probably omit all the `.parent()` selectors and use: `.closest()`.

Comment: Interestingly enough this returns everything as portrait. I also tried to run the script in an isolated environment, just as the snippet you produced, and it works perfectly. It might be a plugin interfering (although I'm barely using any plugins) or a wordpress related issue, considering it works elsewhere. Thank you for the help though, it's greatly appreciated!

Comment: Awesome, consider accepting the answer. Thanks!